# Kotlin sum values in object using lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have a map of  `Map<String, List<VehicleData>>`

```
data class VehicleData{
  var id: Long? = null, 
  var totalKwh: Double? = null,
}
```

I group data by `kwh`

```
"kwh" to List<VehicleData>
```

I need to sum up the `totalKwh` in , my current approach is

```
//assume that i set the data into vehicleDataMap, vehicleDataMap has format of Map<String, List<VehicleData>>
//how can i do the following in functional way in kotlin?
var list = mutableListOf<Number>()
vehicleDataMap.forEach{
    var sumKwh = 0.0
    it.value.forEach{
        sumKwh = sumKwh.plus(it.totalKwh!!)
    }
    list.add(sumKwh)
}
```

How can i do the SUM in functional way? like in kotlin lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map.mapValues` and [`Collections.sumOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html#sumof) (or [`sumByDouble`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html) before Kotlin 1.4):

```kotlin
val res: Map<String, Double> = vehicleDataMap.mapValues {
    (_, v) -> v.sumOf { it.totalKwh ?: 0.0 }
}
```

Or, if you need a `List` as a result:

```kotlin
val res: List<Double> = vehicleDataMap.values.map {
    it.sumOf { it.totalKwh ?: 0.0 }
}
```

Comment: The second one is more relevant. Forgot about map lambda :'|

Answer (score 2):

```
it.value.sumOf {it.totalKwh!!}
```

This should work.